# Migrating a WordPress site to localhost

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have just followed the following guide on manually migrating a WordPress site to localhost: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-move-live-wordpress-site-to-local-server/

I have followed all of the steps: **downloading** files using FTP, **exporting** database, **importing** to localhost database, **changing url** links to localhost and finally updating `wp-config.php`

I tried this on two of my sites and came across different problems:

1. 'Safari cannot connect to the server' error message
2. The following text displayed on the screen:

   ```
   <?php
   /**
   * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
   * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
   *
   * @package WordPress
   */

   /**
   * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
   *
   * @var bool
   */
   define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

   /** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
   require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
   ```

[Image of this error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yu3DF.png)

Can anyone advise as to how I can make my website display?

Comment: does your local server is running?

Comment: Yes it is, as my other websites are working on localhost and MAMP is on..

Comment: please add screenshot of browser, where above code is printed. (Must include address bar)

Comment: please paste address bar URL here, as we can only see localhost in screenshot

Comment: It is http://localhost/public_html/ (the location of my files)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your server is not treating the .php files as PHP. Rather, it is simply serving the .php files in plaintext.
I'm not familiar enough with MAMP to say how to fix this, but perhaps adding the [mamp](/questions/tagged/mamp) tag would help bring in people with more knowledge if [Atlas_Gondal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45123200/8309965) doesn't work.

(I think this would be more appropriate as a comment,  I'm a new user and my rep is too low to comment. ☹️)

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 possible issues:

**Invalid Directory** (High Chance)

It looks like either files are not under MAMP directory OR MAMP is not pointing to that directory.

**Solution:**

If you have MAMP PRO:

1. Launch MAMP PRO
2. Click on HOSTS tab
3. Localhost will be there (if not then add by clicking on `+` icon at left bottom)
4. Choose Document Root (click on three dotted directory for browsing)

If you have standard MAMP:

1. Open MAMP
2. Select Preferences
3. Select Apache (You will be able to see the current location of your document root)
4. Click on the object next to the ‘Document Root:‘
5. Select the new location for your document root
6. click on the ‘Select‘ button
7. Select OK MAMP automatically stops and starts the Apache and MySQL server

**PHP parsing is disabled** (Less Chances)

**Solution:**

1. Edit this file in any editor:

   ```
   /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf
   ```
2. Search for `#AddHandler type-map`
3. Add this code, (below that line)

   ```
   AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
   ```
4. Save the file
5. Restart MAMP.

Lemme know, if none of it works

Answer (score 0):

-> İnstall xampp or appserv (etc.) your computer.

-> Start apache and Mysql (for xampp)

-> Download files to server file (xampp -> htdocs, appserv ->www)

-> Open phpmyadmin and create database with the same name on your host

-> İmport data

-> Configure your wp-config file,

```
// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'dbname');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'username');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
```

-> Replace Url's

```
UPDATE wp_options set option_value=REPLACE(option_value,'Site Url','127.0.0.1') where option_name='siteurl';

UPDATE wp_options set option_value=REPLACE(option_value,'Site Url','127.0.0.1') where option_name='home';

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content=REPLACE(post_content,'Site Url', '127.0.0.1') ;
```

I follow these steps and it works for me. Maybe you could have skipped a few steps

Comment: I have literally done that and have just double checked my database. It must be something small that I am missing but I cannot work it out..

Answer (score 0):

You need to download All in One WP Migration WordPress plugin first you need to setup on your live website then take a backup from there .wpress extension.

After that, you just need to install a basic version of WordPress to your localhost and activate this plugin to your local site and import the backup which you created from your live site. You don't need to create and rename databases or anything this plugin will do everything for you.