# How to get locally running copy of Wordpress Site installed on remote server?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, mamp

I've spent a couple of days on this and it's probably an easy problem to fix, so I appreciate the help. I have MAMP installed and running locally with the document root path pointed to a folder named `websites`. In this folder I have 2 Wordpress websites, one that is working (website 1) and one that is not (website 2). **I'd like help getting the Wordpress website that is not working (website 2) to work. The problem I'm trying to solve is to get a locally running version of a Wordpress site that was created using a one-click install feature from my hosting provider. This remote site has significant work that I'd like to replicate locally so I can improve it.**

When I copy the remote Wordpress files, generated by my hosting provider, into my local websites folder, using FTP, Wordpress does not run at all, because it needs to connect to the database. I exported the data using phpMYAdmin from my remote site and imported it into my local phpMyAdmin and tried updating the wp-config.php file to reflect the local changes. However, the local site will not connect to the database, unless I completely reinstall Wordpress (losing all the changes to the site that I'm trying to download in the first place). The moral is I can't run the install process without losing my work.

The error that is displayed in the browser when I navigate to the second(not working) site, without running the install process, depends on what I have saved in the wp-config file:

**Configuration #1: Inputs to incorrect working website 1 database - DB1**

- DB_Name = 'website_1_DB' //can't use this db
- DB_User = 'local'
- DB_Password = 'SHA1'
- DB_Host = 'localhost'

localhost:8888/website1/ -> Output: Website 1 works fine

localhost:8888/website2/ -> Output: `Error Establishing a Database Connection in Wordpress`

Note: the above configuration was used in two different web-config.php files for both website1 and website 2.

**Configuration #2: Correct DB2 and root user**

For this configuration, I have confirmed in phpMyAdmin > DB2 > Privileges that root has 'All Privileges'

- DB_Name = 'website_2_DB'
- DB_User = 'root'
- DB_Password = 'root'
- DB_Host = 'localhost'

localhost:8888/website2/ ->  Output: ERR_Connection_Refused

**Configuration #3: Correct DB2 and added user from DB1**

For this configuration, I've essentially used the user from Configuration #1 (working user) with DB2 (correct DB)

- DB_Name = 'website_2_DB' //can't use this db
- DB_User = 'local'
- DB_Password = 'SHA1'
- DB_Host = 'localhost'

localhost:8888/website2/ -> Output: It wants to run the Wordpress Install Process

---

Additional Information:

- I have debugging turned on.
- The table prefix seems to be accurate.
- I've read these articles and posts.

  - [How to Fix the Error Establishing a Database Connection in Wordpress](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-the-error-establishing-a-database-connection-in-wordpress/)
  - [How to Edit wp-config.php File in Wordpress](https://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-edit-wp-config-php-file-in-wordpress/)
  - [Beginner's Guide to Wordpress Database Management with phpMyAdmin](https://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/beginners-guide-to-wordpress-database-management-with-phpmyadmin/)
  - [How Wordpress Actually Works Behind the Scenes (Infographic)](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-wordpress-actually-works-behind-the-scenes-infographic/)
  - [Migrating a WordPress site to localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45122387/migrating-a-wordpress-site-to-localhost/45123200#45123200)
  - [Connect Wordpress to the database](https://www.linkedin.com/learning/installing-and-running-wordpress-shared-hosting-2/connect-wordpress-to-the-database?u=42275329)
  - [Wordpress: Workflows (2015)](https://www.linkedin.com/learning/wordpress-workflows-2015/setting-up-a-local-development-environment?u=42275329)
  - I changed the web-config-sample.php to web-config.php essentially installing a new instance of Wordpress, which did connect to the correct DB1. However, **what I'm trying to do is work on the Wordpress site that was created on the remote server. I'm trying to avoid having to reinstall the theme and update the configurations locally, but is this the only way? It seems like I should be able to move the whole installation back and forth between the server and localhost, with different configuration files, as different versions.**

I think the problem is my method for migrating the website from the remote server where it was originally  installed using my hosting service's 'one-click-install.' I just downloaded all the Wordpress files using FTP, then I then exported and imported the database using phpMyAdmin, updating the siteUrl to be as follows:

```
INSERT INTO `wp_options` (`option_id`, `option_name`, `option_value`, `autoload`) VALUES
(1, 'siteurl', 'http://localhost:8888/website2/', 'yes'),
(2, 'home', 'http://localhost:8888/website2/', 'yes'),
```

For website 1 (working locally), I followed a tutorial, but I can't remember which one. According to this [infographic](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-wordpress-actually-works-behind-the-scenes-infographic/), there are a lot of places for me to look, does anyone have any clue where to start? Am I on the right path? It's obviously possible since I've done it before, but I've forgotten how I did it.

> **The bottom line is, how do I get a locally running copy of my remote Wordpress site?**

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I asked @mor10 on Twitter and he said: "Use a migrator plugin like WP Migrate DB or similar, and consider using a tool like Local by Flywheel in place of MAMP." https://twitter.com/mor10/status/1260998219502239745

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend moving manually as it is quite a lot of work. You could use a WordPress Backup/Migration Tool to make this task easier. These plugins replace all the URLs automatically and you don't have to do anything.

- Install a backup plugin on local WordPress site like [Updraft](https://wordpress.org/plugins/updraftplus/) or [Duplicator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/).
- Backup your website completely with the plugin.
- Research and wisely choose the [best web hosting provider](https://www.techknowledger.com/choose-the-best-web-hosting-provider) for your WordPress site.
- Get a domain name and setup the nameserver correctly to the web host (remote server).
- Install the same backup plugin on your web host (remote server).
- Upload the backup of your website via the backup plugin.
- Done. Now your website will be live on your domain in your web host (remote server).

**NOTE**: If you are using some kind of page builder plugin on WordPress like Elementor, ensure to replace the existing URL (`http://localhost/`) with the new URL (`https://example.com`) using Elementor's Settings and Regenerate the CSS using Elementor's Settings.

*You can find these settings on:*

- WP Admin > Elementor > Tools > Replace URL
- WP Admin > Elementor > Tools > Regenerate CSS

Answer (score 0):

I know the paint that you faced. I also run WordPress on my VPS. You might want to check updraft plugin to backup all your remote files and install them back to your local machine.

Or another thing is, I recommended that you use duplicator plugin. Good luck

Comment: Thank you! I am kind of trying to avoid using plugins, as I feel like third party dependencies increase the attack surface of this already vulnerable technology. However, I don't think that there is much of a choice, as I'm not sure where the issue originates. The ideal state is having the most recent copy of the remote site to run locally with the proper database, however, the complexity of changing the URLs (found here: https://wordpress.org/support/article/moving-wordpress/) a.) seems irrelevant to getting the splash page to work and b.) is an inordinate amount of work to test if it's true.

Comment: When you use duplicator plugin, it's all about one click to install from your remote server to the local server. You don't need to think about any changing URL again. I always work with this plugin and I never encounter any problems.